# routes.IgnoreRoute is not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I m new to MVC3 and just have started learning it, today is my first day with it and I m using default MVC3 template. I need to ignore calls to css files. Please note CSS files are placed in Content folder which is on root.

What I have tried ?

```
            routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.css");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
```

With first line of code I have one by one tried these 3 lines of code but it did not work. Kindly guide.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more of what you are trying to achive with code samples of how you are including you css?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: These comments are really nonsense.simply he wants to restrict user from accessing any html file. but it does not work at all. I've been pulling my hairs out for this but all in vain.

Answer (score 0):

By default, MVC does not route requests for static files. It creates a url path to them just like non-mvc asp.net.

Unless you are explicitly asking MVC to deliver them.

You can do this by adding the following in the web.config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

This means that every request, including those for static content is hitting the pipeline.

Change this setting to:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
```

To stop this from happening.